# How do plants that grow underground legumes/nuts distribute their seeds?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy

It makes perfect sense to me when plants employ some sort of method of distributing their offspring some distance from the mother plant. If the mother plant dies due to that location not being ideal, the offspring could potentially find somewhere better. Though, plants like peanut plants that grow their seeds in the same location don't make sense to me. How do their seeds travel distances and spread across land? How is this method effective enough to be passed down through evolution? It seems awfully counter intuitive to me. I tried figuring this out on google but couldn't find anything that answered this.

Comment: How do other seeding plants spread their progeny - might this still apply?

Comment: the plants you mention in your question uses bacteria to convert nitrogen to nitrate,so the plants provide fertilizer to the soil where it places the seeds.

Comment: Searching for "how do peanuts spread" lead me to http://bioweb.uwlax.edu/bio203/s2012/steinmet_vero/reproduction.htm, an excellent site where your question is answered (considering peanuts).